# Can i add an EventListener to a class i make in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am a new programmer to Javascript and i was wondering if i could add an addEventListener to a class i made in an innerHTML tag.

I would like to click it the class 'favo_btn' and give a uniek console.log to it.

```
   let str = '';
    str = document.createElement('div');
    if (result.results !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < result.results.length; i++) {
            console.log(result.results.length);
            str.innerHTML += `
            <div>
            <h2>${result.results[i].title}</h2>
            <img class="images" src="${result.results[i].thumbnail}">
            <p>${result.results[i].title}</p>
            <button class="favo_btn> <3 </button>
            </div>
            `
            ;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const element = str.querySelector('selector');
element.addEventListener('click', ()=> {console.log(element.className)})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('.favo_btn').addEventListener('click', function(event){
console.log(event.target);
});
```

That will give your element.